# VBScript/VBA quitting an Excel application is affected by standard Excel events

Tags: vba, excel, stored-procedures, vbscript

I use Task Scheduler to manage a VBScript which starts a vba sub procedure in Workbook X. This procedure opens two other Workbooks  and move data to Workbook X and closes them again. The procedure outcome is an updated Workbook X which I need to save. The VBA procedure works fine and is triggered by the VBScript as expected. However, the part of the VBScript which should save the file doesn't work. The VBScript is based on code I have found on Stackoverflow.com and other sites. 
When I open the file X I tried to save with the VBScript, It asks me to decide whether I want to save the file. If I do, I can see the data the above procedure has created has worked.
I can see in the Task Manager that the Excel instance I have created with the VBScript is never closed although I tried to do it in the VBScript. I have also tried the Save method, but with no luck. I have tried different parameters for the methods with no luck. I have search on this site and other sites for how the issue could be solved. However, they suggest Save and SaveAs methods and I tried them with the different suggested parameter configurations without success.

I have now found the root cause but not the solution. It has nothing to do with the script itself. In the open workbook event.
I have code which activate a userform (StartUpForm.Show). In the workbook before close and open events I call procedure RemoveFilter which remove a filter on a set of filtered data. If I mark UserForm.Show and the RemoveFilter in the before close workbook event as notation it works. It is not enough to avoid call StartUpForm.Show. StartUpForm.Show needs to be marked as notation or deleted. How can that be? And is there a workaround?

This doesn't work:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim batRun As Boolean

    RemoveFilter
    ResolveStartUp (batRun)
    If Not batRun Then
       StartUpForm.Show vbModal
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    RemoveFilter
End Sub
```

This works:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim batRun As Boolean

    RemoveFilter
    ResolveStartUp (batRun)
    If Not batRun Then
       ' StartUpForm.Show vbModal
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ' RemoveFilter
End Sub
```

VBScript:

```
On Error Resume Next

ImportAccesFilesToHolidaysAndWorkshops

Sub ImportAccesFilesToHolidaysAndWorkshops() 

  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open ("Z:\ResourceManagement\Holiday and workshops input.xlsm", 0, False,,,,,,,,True)
  xlApp.Run "ImportResourcesAndProjects"
  xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close

  xlBook.SaveAs "Z:\ResourceManagement\Holiday and workshops input.xlsm",,,,,,xlExclusive, xlLocalSessionChanges

  xlBook.Close
  Set xlBook = Nothing 

  xlApp.Quit 
  Set xlApp = Nothing 

  WScript.Echo "Finished."
  WScript.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `xlBook.Save` if you are expecting to overwrite the existing file - `.SaveAs`is trying to save a copy of the file

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have tried it. However, if you read my edited description of the issue you will see I have found the issue, but not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving to your C: drive. If that works you are probably running into a scheduled task problem. If the task runs whether or not a user is logged in or it is set to use highest privileges, you aren't running under the security context you think you are. In either of those cases job scheduler will use S4U authentication which will prevent you from accessing network resources. I'm guessing that Z: drive is a mapped network drive. Mapped drives belong to the user who mapped the drive so it won't be available unless you are running as the user that mapped the drive and that user is logged in.

If you use "run with highest privileges", you are actually running under the built in Administrator account. That is a separate account and it won't have your drive mappings.

[Task Security Context](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152(v=ws.11).aspx)

[Some Programs Cannot Access Network Locations When UAC Is Enabled](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx)

[windows 7 scheduled tasks run with highest privileges](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%207%20scheduled%20tasks%20run%20with%20highest%20privileges&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. I did what you suggested to run it on my C drive. I ran into the same problem as described above. However, this time it seems as if my effort to avoid pop-ups didn't work.